# Opening Previously Downloaded Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-sqlite, firebase-storage

So, this program downloads a file from firebase storage,
my downloading code is:

```
private void downloadFiles(Context context, String fileName, String destinationDirectory, String url) {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName);

    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}

public void downloading(final String name) {
    downloadRef = storage.getInstance().getReference().child(name);
    downloadRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String url = uri.toString();
            downloadFiles(Main2Activity.this, name,  Environment.getExternalStorageState((File) Downloads), url);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Failed!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and then I want to use this database so I tried to open it with:

```
database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Environment.getExternalStorageState((File) Downloads) + "/" + name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

but it says

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

How can I solve this one?

Comment: It's hard to say where the problem comes from. To troubleshoot I'd recommend pulling the sqlite file from your Android device with a device manager, and then see if you can open it locally. If not, you at least know the problem is in how you download and save the data, and you're in a better position to investigate what is wrong with the file from the device.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hey again! I tried to open my database file with sqlite editor from my emulator, and it works, there is a problem with the opening database

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hey, I really hope I am not disturbing you, but I am hopeless right now, I tried to search the whole internet but couldn't work it out, is there any way you can help me?